# How to get an html table back to a Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'll use the famous NerdDinner as an example here.

I have a search page where the user can enter a search string and then see the result in a table below. The user can also add more results to the table, like this:

- Search for dinners today and display in a table.
- Search for dinners tomorrow and **add** the result to the table.
- The table will now show dinners today and tomorrow.

The user is also able to remove dinners from the table by clicking on them, one by one.

I need to generate a pdf with the results in the table. Not like a print screen because the pdf has it's own layout. I just need the data in the table. Preferably in a list of **Dinner** models.

Right now I can generate a pdf from a list of **Dinner** models. But once I've printed them to the table and the user has manipulated it I don't know how to get it back to a list of **Dinner** models.

Another solution could be to keep the Id's hidden in the table and then do another search in the DB with the Id's from the table (after the user has manipulated it). At least then I would get the result in the form of a list of **Dinners**. But this seems redundant to me.

Has anyone had a similar problem and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the table inside an html `<form>` and on each row in addition to the label you could have a hidden field:

```
@model IEnumerable<Dinner>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Prop1</th>
                <th>Prop2</th>
                <th>Prop3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorForModel()
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Export to PDF" />
}
```

and in the editor template:

```
@model Dinner
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Prop1)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Prop1)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Prop2)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Prop2)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Prop3)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Prop3)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now this form could be submitted to the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult GeneratePdf(IEnumerable<Dinner> dinners)
{
    byte[] pdf = ...
    return File(pdf, "application/pdf", "dinners.pdf");
}
```

You may also checkout the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) for managing a variable length list in order to keep input field names in sync for the binder when adding/removing elements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this after the weekend. I'm not using Razor but I guess it's not that big a difference?

Comment: @Niklas, not a big difference, `@` => `<%=` :-)

Comment: Would it be more efficient to just submit the id's from the table back to the server, then fetch the records with those id's. I'd save some output to the browser but I'd have to go back to the DB once more. It's an admin tool so there won't be many simultaneous users. Your opinion?

Comment: @Niklas, yes it would be more efficient to submit only the ids.